# How to break x-axis with // marking?

Tags: matlab, formatting, axis

I want to break x-axis with // marking.

I have found some similar written scripts for this purpose, for instance: `breakxaxis` (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/42905-break-x-axis).

However, I am looking for a more professional look with only the // marking in the axis like the following:

[image]

Comment: No built-in way. Relevant: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/42537-break-in-the-axis

Comment: I have found those as well but imo those aren't professional looking enough

Comment: Then develop something that you think looks professional using those as a reference?

Comment: I will, but I was hoping someone else might have already done it or that I was overlooking some kind of option.

Comment: @Suever How does that help in any way? It's clear there's a demand for this

Comment: @jimbob97 I linked an additional reference, is that not helpful? Just because there is a demand for some functionality doesn't mean that the solution has already been created. Feel free to contribute one to the community to satisfy the demand and post it here as an answer.